# Gravando um texto no Mysql

Tags: php

Desenvolvi o código abaixo para salvar o conteúdo de arquivos pdf no banco de dados.

Como não consegui fazer isso direto do pdf para o banco, fiz o seguinte processo:

- extraio o texto do um pdf e gero um txt com o conteúdo;
- transformo o conteúdo desse txt em string;
- Salvo o conteúdo no banco.

No todo, o programa está funcionando, porém não 100%.
Quando eu salvo o conteúdo do txt através da aplicação html que eu fiz, ele salva no banco, somente as 3 últimas palavras do texto.

**Segue o código abaixo:**

```
<?php

set_time_limit(6000);

include_once ("conexao.php");

ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF8');

$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_fnl = $_FILES['file']['name'];

exec('tet --text '. $file_fnl);
$name = substr($file_fnl, 0, -4);
$file_txt = $name.'.txt';

$dados = file($file_txt);

foreach ($dados as $stringArray){
    
    $stringArrayF = ''.$stringArray;
    
    $DCM_nome = $file_fnl;
    $DCM_conteudo = $stringArrayF;  
    
    echo $DCM_conteudo; 
}

$result = "INSERT INTO test.conteudo_dcm (DCM_nome, DCM_conteudo) VALUES ('$DCM_nome','$DCM_conteudo');";

$_result = mysqli_query($conn,$result);

?>
```

Para saber se seria um problema do banco, executei a linha do insert direto no workbench, só que troquei a variável que guarda o texto, pelo texto propriamente dito... e funcionou. Todo o conteúdo foi salvo no banco.

Com isso, acredito (tenho quase certeza) que o problema deve estar no meu php.

Comment: `exec('tet --text  '. $file_fnl);` O que esse `tet` faz?

Comment: @AugustoVasques É uma biblioteca que extrai o texto do pdf e gera um arquivo txt com o conteúdo, entre outras funcionalidades.

Comment: Já fez o print_r($dados) para verificar se o arquivo está sendo gerado e os dados estão corretos? Eu não vou apresentar uma solução antes dessa verificação.

Comment: Sim. Os dados estão sendo gerados corretamente. Acredito que o problema esteja na construção do foreach, mas já tentei de diversas formas e nada.

Answer (score 0):

Troque o `foreach` e seu conteúdo por [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) que junta elementos de uma matriz em uma string.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(6000);

include_once ("conexao.php");

ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF8');

$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_fnl = $_FILES['file']['name'];

exec('tet --text '. $file_fnl);
$name = substr($file_fnl, 0, -4);
$file_txt = $name.'.txt';

$dados = file($file_txt);

$DCM_conteudo = implode(' ', $dados); // transforma o string array $dados numa string.

$DCM_nome = $file_fnl;

$result = "INSERT INTO test.conteudo_dcm (DCM_nome, DCM_conteudo) VALUES ('$DCM_nome','$DCM_conteudo');";

$_result = mysqli_query($conn,$result);

?>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!!!!